# Can't use the setOnClickListener with ListViews - "D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called"

Tags: android, listview

I'm quite new at developing applications on android and I'm blocked with my current project: I try to receive information from a database on a server and show them on a list.

I was able to do so but can't find a way to use the setOnItemClickListener to be able to reach another activity (can't click on it). It throws the following message when I play the application:

`"D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called".`

Here is the part of the code I made:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    listView_Formular = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEquipment);

    listView_Formular.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(History_Formular.this, Work_Order_Resume.class);
            String message = "abc";
            TextView nom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID_name);

            intent.putExtra("id_formular", nom.getText().toString());
            System.out.println(nom.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });`
```

I tried to put the setOnClickListener() in the invokeWS() method but did not change anything (here is the invokeWS() with the onSuccess() )

```
public void invokeWSGet(RequestParams params){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get( "http://192.168.1.20:8181/RestServer/iscs/workorders/",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] none, byte[] b) {
            String result = new String(b);
            JSONArray jarr = null;
            List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

            History_Formular.WorkOrderAdapter adapterLayout = new History_Formular.WorkOrderAdapter(History_Formular.this, all_Formular_Json);
            listView_Formular = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEquipment);
            if (listView_Formular.getCount()>0) {
                adapterLayout.clear();
                listView_Formular.setAdapter(adapterLayout);
                listView_Formular.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
            }


            try {
                jarr = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i = 0; i<jarr.length();i++){
                    jsons.add(jarr.getJSONObject(i));
                    Work_Order_POJO work_order_converted = toWork_Order(jsons.get(i));
                    all_Formular_Json.add(i, work_order_converted);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(result);
            String[] all_request = result.split(",");
            for(int i=0; i<all_request.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(all_request[i]);
            }
            // JSON Object
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            adapterLayout = new History_Formular.WorkOrderAdapter(History_Formular.this, all_Formular_Json);
            listView_Formular.setAdapter(adapterLayout);

        }
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line of code from your `onSuccess()` method

```
listView_Formular = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEquipment);
```

Then declare `listView_Formular` variable outside of `onCreate()` method.

```
listView_Formular = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEquipment);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    listView_Formular.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // code inside onClick
        }
    });
}
```